# AJAX : How to make loaded page appear below the page that calls it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Code for my main page:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        div
        {
            width:100%;
            height:100px;
            background-color:rgba(189,123,124,1.00);
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;

            /* make this div TOPMOST */
            z-index:9000;
        }
        .container
        {
            /* make the page that will be loaded appear below the div */
            z-index:200;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div>
            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(window).on("click", function()
                {
                    $("div.container").load("Page1.html");
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
```

As you can see above, I've tried to make the red div bar at the bottom appear topmost, so that when Page1.html is loaded when user clicks the browser window, this red bar at bottom will still be on top.

Now, my code for Page1.html:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    body, html
    {
        height:100%;
    }
    div
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:rgba(171,147,136,1.00);
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>Page One</div>
</body>
```

However, when Page1.html gets loaded, it completely comes on top of the red div bar and the div bar disappears. Seems like Z-Index is useless. How do I fix this?

You can see the actual page here: http://oneniceday.com/SR-1/Test2.html

Comment: is it  that you want it bellow or you want it behind? Z index is used for overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

index

```
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        .footer
        {
            /* make the page that will be loaded appear below the div */
            z-index:200;
             width:100%;
            height:100px;
            background-color:rgba(189,123,124,1.00);
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;

            /* make this div TOPMOST */
            z-index:9000;
        }

        body, html
    {
        height:100%;
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="holder"></div>

     <div class="footer">
            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $(window).on("click", function()
                {
                    $("div.holder").load("Page1.html");
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
```

Page1

```
<style type="text/css">
    .data
    {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:rgba(171,147,136,1.00);
    }
</style>


    <div class="data">Page One</div>
```

I have removed head and body tags from page1, cause you had invalid HTMl. you can't have head tag in your body, or body tag inside body.
Partial views/pages, should not contain header or layout if you append it to existing pages.

Comment: The only problem is that above code doesn't make the loaded page (Page1.html) fill the browser window, so I took out the "body, html" rules in the CSS section and explicitly set .container to height:100%. Tks for your help once more! :-)